# Decision tree complexity of finding parameters of "zigzag" array

Tags: data-structures, decision-tree

I am currently studying for a test on data structures.

I have to find the lower and upper bounds for the following problem:

> An array is called a *zigzag* array if there are $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$ so that the array increases from $1$ to $i$, decreases from $i$ to $j$, and increases from $j$ to $n$.
>
> Input: a zigzag array.
> Output: the position of $i$ and $j$.

My answer:

- Upper bound: just going on the array and finding $i$ and $j$, which takes $O(N)$.
- Lower bound: I think that we need to find pairs $i$ and $j$ for which $k$ is bigger than $i$ in $n$ elements, I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious lower bound is $\Omega(\log n)$, since there are $\binom{n+1}{2}$ possible answers. It is likely that using smart binary search you can find $i,j$ in $O(\log n)$ queries. I suggest starting with the easier case in which $j = n$, that is, the array increases and then decreases, and you want to find its maximum in $O(\log n)$ queries. Such arrays are known as *bitonic*, and indeed you can find $i$ in $O(\log n)$ comparisons (see for example [this solution](http://comproguide.blogspot.co.il/2015/02/finding-maximum-element-in-bitonic-array.html)).

Comment: tnx. but i cant f=understand why log ((n+1)(n)/2) is omega(logn)

Comment: That's a nice exercise for you.